# I Need Help To Install Wine, Synaptic, And Samsung SCX-340SW Driver

Tags: drivers, printing

I need to install wine and synaptic installer.I've tried finding it but no luck.I also need drivers for my wireless printer, it is a samsung scx-340sw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, spelling is important here.

First open a terminal window (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

To install Synaptic package manager, enter the command

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

To install vine, goto te website http://bitblaze.cs.berkeley.edu/release/vine-1.0/howto.html to learn about how to download, compile and install that version of linux.

If, on the otherhand, you are trying to install Wine, use the command

`sudo apt-get install wine`

The samsung printer is not mentioned at http://www.openprinting.org/printers, so support for that particular printer may be difficult.

Comment: i got everything to work but vine.The page you gave me is over my head.

Comment: Over my head too - Vine appears to be a variant of linux aimed particularily at Japanese users (see http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=vine).  The main homepage for vine is written in Kanji, I believe, and unreadable to me.  see http://www.vinelinux.org/

Comment: or let me ask this what is a good app to download that has games and software on it.I used vine in the past i think but this one dont have it.

Comment: I don't do much gaming personally, but I think a lot of people are running a combination of Wine and Steam to do their games

Comment: how do i install stream?

Comment: Not sure - I don't do games very much